# How do I do variable expansion in django custom template tag parameters?

Tags: python, django

I would like to write a custom template tag in Django that will be used like this:

```
{% mytag "/sms/{{ phone.number }}/" %}
```

how do I get django to evaluate the parameter string before passing it to my template tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
{% mytag "/sms/"|add:phone.number %}
```

Comment: I guess it would be `{% mytag "/sms/"|add:phone.number|add:"/" %}` to get the final `/`..  It works (produces the correct result), but the syntax would be too surprising for my users.

Comment: It depends what do you need in `mytag` . If it is url with parameter you can use `{% url 'sms' phone.number as the_url %}` to build correct url and use it later in your tag: `{% mytag the_url %}`

Comment: ...or use both `sms` url name and the variable as arguments for `mytag` and then use them from inside, that would be the cleanest one I think..

Comment: `"/sms/{{ phone.number }}/"` isn't an url.  Syntactically it might be a valid url, but there is no route/view corresponding to it.  I guess marinodev's suggestion could work, something like: `{% mytag "/sms/%s/" phone.number %}` ?